# Ubuntu 16.04 barely using swap

Tags: python, ram, swap

I am trying to setup a server with 4Gb ram using 32bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I ran into an interesting problem that I hope I can get some help with.

I am trying to process some large data files on this new server with python, but python crashes with a memory error (it runs our of ram). I have setup a swap partition with multiple GB's worth of memory but the server barely uses the swap.

Barely is the important word here since roughly 80 Mb worth of swap is being used. Therefore I think (please correct me if I am wrong here) that the swap is setup correctly since the system is using it.

Now I have tried to play with the swapiness, but that does not seem to help (the current value is 100).

The processing of these large data files happens at night and therefore low performance due to swap usage is not a problem.

Would anybody be able to explain to me why Ubuntu might not use it's swap memory and just throw a memory error?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,
Hilbert

Comment: The only solution might be adding more RAM... but that might also mean using a 64-bit OS. Setting vm.swappiness to 100 says "swap a lot" and might be really detrimental to system performance. You might try a newer LTS just to see if it handles things better.

Comment: How much swap have you set up?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE/PentiumM and see if it applies to your configuration.

Comment: I don't know your python script but perhaps dusk writes are being buffered and you should flush them frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit process won't use more that 4GB of memory, real or virtual.

Using [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)[*] allows the OS to use more than 4GB of RAM, but each process is still restricted to 4GB of virtual space.

If you want to use more RAM than this in the process you have to use a 64-bit CPU, a 64-bit OS and 64-bit apps (ie, Python interpreter).

If you want to stick to a 32-bit OS, then see if you can split your python process into several processes that each use under 4GB of RAM.

[*] IIRC all late 32-bit Ubuntu kernels include PAE support.

Comment: re:"A 32bit process won't use more that 4GB of memory, real" this part is accurate... but "... or virtual" may not be accurate. Don't think of swap as a memory extension. It's a function of the system, not the process.

Comment: For a process the swap is transparent, all the memory has to fit in its virtual memory address space. See the PAE link above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wan't aware that a 32 bit Machine is restricted to 4 GB worth of ram. I was able to solve my problem by making my python code more memory efficient. The above answer is great though since I now understand why it didn't work.